# Abstracting ActiveRecord Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, abstraction, abstract-data-type

What is the best way to abstract an ActiveRecord attribute without further normalizing the database?

For example, let's assume a database table named `addresses` with a column `zip_code` and a method to determine if the zip code is valid:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  def zip_code_valid?
    ..
  end
end
```

I would prefer to have:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
end

class ZipCode
  def valid?
    ..
  end
end
```

and when I execute `Address.find(1).zip_code`, it returns a `ZipCode` vs. a string. I would prefer not to normalize the database by creating a table called `zip_codes`. The example is hypothetical, and I currently do not have a real world example of this; I simply want to know how I could potentially do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this for `ZipCode` as you discussed, but to answer your question, you should consider using Rails Aggregations.

Here's the documentation :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html

If you have specific questions about things you want to accomplish, let me know and I can try to answer those specific questions.

Comment: Thank you. The example with address and zip code was an example that I quickly thought up to explain what I would like to potentially do. I am trying to find the best way to abstract an ActiveRecord attribute without further normalizing the database. I will look at the documentation you linked to.

Comment: I assumed as much. I've done the same thing many times, it's easier to explain with an example but sometimes it's hard to think of an easy to describe example that makes sense. I hope you find what you're looking for in Aggregations. Let me know if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think abstracting the zip code out into a class makes sense if you're not going to do the same with the street, house number, city, etc. You already have it as a separate column in the Address table, so it doesn't make sense to store it in its own class (from an ActiveRecord point of view). Alternatively, if you store zip codes in their own table (and hence class), what are you gaining? In my opinion it's going too far to keep a single attribute in a separate class/table if it makes sense as to be part of the aggregate that it's currently in.

Comment: Thank you. This is a hypothetical question about pushing abstraction to the brink. This question crossed my mind last night as I was reading Code Complete and the section on abstract data types.

While it may be going too far, let's assume in the future there will be a couple dozen methods that relate only to the zip code, in which case I believe it would be beneficial to have the methods abstracted into ZipCode vs Address.

Comment: If you're going to place judgement on the question, you should at least provide an answer first.

Comment: @jesse - Are you kidding me? You realize that I did provide an answer right? My answer is that he should stick with the first example he provided, and not abstract it into its own class. Another voter realized that and voted me up. It's obvious that I read the question if I provided an in-depth answer as to why he should avoid placing zip code into its own class.

Comment: @McStretch, Andrew asked the community how to "take ActiveRecord attributes and abstract it?" you told him that he shouldn't abstract it, isn't that a non-answer? Further, you asked him, "if you store zip codes in their own table, what are you gaining?" when he clearly stated he did not want to store the zip codes in their own table. This would imply that you did not read the question closely. Finally, your assumption that a new class requires a new database table is faulty. I down voted your answer for all of those reasons.

Comment: @jesse - How is it a non-answer to confirm that the way he initially had it may be the best? As for your second point, storing the zipcode in a different class could go hand in hand with creating a new table (which he admits by saying "I would prefer not to normalize the database by creating a table called zip_codes."), so it's important to take that into account. I didn't say it always does, but my point directly targets his point about avoiding creating a new table. And guess what? His initial solution, which I endorsed, does just that.

Comment: @McStretch If he asked if he was heading in the right direction, I could understand your point of view, however, he asked how to accomplish a very specific task about "pushing abstraction to the brink". He showed you a loaf of bread and asked you how to slice it and you told him to just eat it as a loaf. That's a critique, not an answer.

Comment: @jesse - There are many answers like this on SO, and I find them to be very useful, as do many other users. In your opinion, if someone asks "where should I store user's passwords in plaintext on my server" then anyone who answers "Don't store passwords in plaintext!" should be downvoted because they didn't answer his specific question?

Comment: @McStretch Exactly. I think it's right to add a caveat that what you're explaining is a bad idea, however, don't assume that you know better than they do whether it's a good idea. I assume that Andrew knows much more about his application than I do, and therefore I will explain how to accomplish what he asks, with the caveat that in general it's not a good idea. I once asked how to access Rails session information in a model and was told that it's a bad idea. I know it's a bad idea, in general, but at the moment, I needed to do it. Don't judge someone's solution without all the info.

Comment: @jesse - So I answered the question based on the example Andrew gave. He commented on my answer right before you downvoted me giving me more info to work on. Based on the info he gave me, my response is a perfectly valid answer. As you said yourself, "I'm not sure why you'd want to do this for ZipCode as you discussed...".

Comment: @McStretch, I'm tired of arguing about this, I have better things to do. Read through everything again, and maybe you'll understand better where I'm coming from. If not, continue on as you were, judgemental as always.

Comment: @jesse - Haha "judgemental as always"? So you know me now? It's ironic that you call me judgemental.